# create time stamp and compare time by mysql field

Tags: php, mysql

there is a table with these fields

```
month
year
day
```

and these files are contain numbers like

```
year = 2001 and month = 10 and day = 25
```

and i have `time stamp` in php 
so i need to compare these in mysql

something like:

```
select * from times where mktime(year,month,day)<1235478554
```

is there any function in mysql for this?
i need to make time stamp in mysql with the mysql fields...

UPDATE 1 :
i used like this and not worked

```
SELECT * from work_result where UNIX_TIMESTAMP('year-month-day 00:00:00')<1
```

UPDATE2:
[image]

Comment: @putvande it not worked in my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's [UNIX_TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) which will get you the Unix timestamp of a given date string. Which means you need to build a date string inline in your MySQL query. Doing so is considered bad style, you should propably be storing a Unix timestamp within your database.

Comment: i used like this and not worked `SELECT * from work_result where UNIX_TIMESTAMP('year-month-day 00:00:00')<1 `

Comment: Yeah, of course that won't work. You're generating the Timestamp for the year "year", the month "month" and so on. Running a  *SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('year-month-day 00:00:00')* will show you what I mean.

Comment: i added the result image!!